# MySqlConnection open() never returns

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySql database in order to extract some data. I installed the MySqlConnector but my code doesn't seem to work. It never goes out from the `try` block (it never prints `Connection OK`). What can it be?

```
string server = "serverIpAddress";
string database = "dbName";
string uid = "userName";
string password = "****";

string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Trying to open"); 
    myConnection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection OK");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Even if I remove the Console.ReadKey(); statement, nothing happens. It's still waiting forever

Comment: You should place this in the catch: `Console.WriteLine(e.Message); if(e.InnerException != null) Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);`. This way, the exception message (and inner-exception message if it exists) will be written to the screen.

Comment: Still nothing... Waits forever.

Comment: Yes, but it never enters the catch block. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: I read this page [MySQL Connector/Net connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/). Shouldn't `PASSWORD` be `Pwd`?

Comment: @Abbas works as well with PASSWORD

Comment: It seems to be a connection timeout problem. Could you ask to your MySql Administrator how is configured the timeout value on your server? If you try to change the Server IP Address to something inexistant do your code exit with a proper exception?

Comment: Oki, didn't know that, just trying to rule out the possibilities of the cause. How long do you wait? Do you get a time-out?

Comment: Yes, if I use a wrong server address, it catches the error.

Comment: So the problem lies in your MySql server address, it is right but something doesn't work there. Did you try to connect to this server using the MySql Administrative Tools (Workbench or command line utility) ? If they fail then it is definitively a problem with your database not with your code.

Comment: It's something wrong with the code. I can access the DB from a php application, using the same parameters.